# Every measure on a set $X$ extends to the power set of $X$: Consistent or not with ZF?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, measure-theory

> **Question.** Is it consistent with ZF that *every* (countably additive, non-negative) measure $\mu: \Sigma \to \bf R$, where $\Sigma$ is a sigma-algebra on a given set $X$, extends to a (countably additive, non-negative) measure $\tilde{\mu}: \mathcal P(X) \to \bf R$?

What I seem to know: Let us first work in the frame of ZFC. Given a set $X$ of cardinality $\ge \aleph_1$, we take $\Sigma$ to be the smallest sigma-algebra on $X$ containing all the countable subsets of $X$. It is seen that the function 
$$\mu: \Sigma \to {\bf R}: A \mapsto 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\! 0 & \text{if } |A| \le \aleph_0 \\
\! 1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
is a measure on $X$. Thus, if $\mu$ extends to a (countably additive, non-negative) measure $\mathcal P(X) \to \bf R$, then $|X|$ is a real-valued measurable cardinal, which implies the existence of a weakly inaccessible cardinal by an old theorem of S. Ulam, see

> S. Ulam, *Zur Masstheorie in der allgemeinen Mengenlehre*, Fund. Math. **16** (1930), 140-150 (in German),

or Corollary 10.15 in:

> T. Jech, *Set Theory - The Third Millennium Edition, Revised and Expanded*, Springer Monogr. Math., Springer, Berlin, 2006 (corrected 4th printing).

However, the existence of a weakly inaccessible cardinal is unprovable from the axioms of ZFC.

On the other hand, we have from:

> R. M. Solovay, ``Real-valued measurable cardinals'', pp. 397-428 in: D. Scott (ed.), *Axiomatic set theory*, Proc. Sympos. Pure Math. (Univ. California, Los Angeles, CA, 1967), Vol. XIII, Part I, Amer. Math. Soc.: Providence, RI, 1987 (reprinted ed.)

that the existence of measurable cardinals in ZF is equiconsistent with the existence of measurable (resp., real-valued measurable) cardinals in ZFC. However, this doesn't answer the question I'm posing, as far as I can say (in particular, it occurs to me that Solovay's result doesn't cover the case of real-valued measurable cardinals in ZF, does it?).

Comment: Actually Solovay's original result was that it is equiconsistent with ZFC that in ZF there is a total extension of the Lebesgue measure. I'm not sure about its additivity, though, because you are losing countable choice there and the whole thing about additivity becomes quite fussy then.

Comment: Your title is also misleading. You ask "true or false" but you actually ask "consistent or inconsistent". If something is not provable from ZFC it will certainly not be provable from ZF.

Comment: Right. I'm editing the title according to your comment.

Comment: (Solovay's original result is from 1965, by the way.)

Comment: Really? I'm relying on second-hand information concerning Solovay's result. So, please, feel free to fix the OP and provide the correct reference!

Comment: Well, if I recall correctly it was published as a notice on Notices of AMS. So I'm afraid I will only be able to verify that next week. "The measure problem." Notices of the American Mathematical Society vol. 12 (1965) p. 217.

Comment: Wasn't the 1965 notice just an abstract? That's what I had understood, and by a closer look at the paper cited in the OP (I was addressed to it by some colleagues who explained the result was first proved there, which is the "second-hand information" I was referring to in the above) I've just realized there is a footnote on p. 397 (actually, the very 1st page of the article), where the author explains that "The main results of this paper were proved in the spring of 1966."

Comment: An abstract in Notices of AMS does not mean there was no paper behind it. I saw the handwritten notes of Azriel Levy for some of the abstracts he posted in the 60s (specifically the one where the Levy collapse was defined and its applications for definable measurable sets first came up). Just because the paper wasn't published because at the time people weren't publishing every new comma they wrote, doesn't mean there wasn't an actual factual result.

Comment: I see. Yet, I think I will stick to the reference provided in the OP, all the more that it includes the footnote copied in my previous comment.

Comment: On the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ of all either meager or comeager Borel subsets of $X$ $\coloneqq$ the real line, the probability measure being zero at the meager and one at the comeager sets is not extendible to a measure on all Borel sets of $X$.  Is this relevant to your question?

Comment: For $\mathcal A$ to actually be a $\sigma$-algebra, it think one needs that countable unions of countable sets are countable. The proof of nonextendibility I presently know uses Hahn-Banach, though. It is in  https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001:1999:45::152  in Remark 3.2 c), with minor misprints.

Answer (score 7):

> **EDIT:** This answer is wrong. I am not deleting it at the request of the OP. See the counterexample at the bottom.

Here is a terrible mathematician answer that you didn't know that you didn't care for. Yes, it is consistent, at least assuming the consistency of very large cardinals.

In Gitik's model, where every limit ordinal has countable cofinality we also have the following: If we start with the class of singletons and close it under countable unions, we obtain the entire universe. And I claim that in the presence of this axiom, every countably additive measure is either atomic (and thus extends naturally) or trivial (and thus extends naturally).

To see why, if the measure gives $0$ to singletons, then by $\sigma$-additivity it has to give $0$ to every countable set, and so to every set which can be generated by a countable union of countable sets. Which is *every* set. If there are singletons which have positive measure, then they are necessarily the atoms and we're done.

Some relevant papers:

> 1. *Arnold W. Miller*, [**Long Borel hierarchies**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/malq.200710044), *MLQ Math. Log. Q.* **54** (2008), no. 3, 307--322.
> 2. *M. Gitik*, [**All uncountable cardinals can be singular**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02760939), *Israel J. Math.* **35** (1980), no. 1-2, 61--88.

---

***Edit.*** So here is a counterexample, and some consequence of it.

In Gitik's model, $\Bbb R$ is a countable union of sets $A_n$, such that each $A_n$ is the countable union of countable sets. In particular, there is a countable sequence of countable sets $X_n$ whose union is uncountable.

Now, if $X_n$ is countable $R_n=\{r\in\Bbb R\mid r\text{ codes an enumeration of }X_n\}$ gives us a family without a choice function. If we could choose $r_n\in R_n$ then we could have enumerated all the $X_n$'s uniformly and their union would have been countable.

Now consider $\Sigma$ as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $R_n$'s, and since they are obvious pairwise disjoint (a real cannot code more than one countable set), $\Sigma$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ with $R_n$ as atoms.

If we consider the atomic measure on $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ such that $\mu(\{n\})=1/2^{n+1}$, it induced a measure on $\Sigma$. Now I claim that $\mu$ cannot be extended to a measure on $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$.

Suppose that it could have been extended, then it is impossible that *every* singleton has measure $0$, since $\sigma$-additivity would have implied that every countable set has measure $0$, thus every $A_n$ (from the partition of $\Bbb R$) has measure $0$ as a countable union of null sets; and finally $\Bbb R$ has measure $0$. But this is impossible since $\mu(\Bbb R)=1$.

So each $R_n$ has some countable subset whose elements have all positive measure summing to $1/2^{n+1}$. But if $\sum_n r_n<\infty$ it has to be the case that for every $k$, at most finitely many $r_n$'s satisfy $\frac1k < r_n$. So there is a finite set of reals with maximal weight inside each $R_n$.

So we have $R'_n\subseteq R_n$, finite sets of reals defined as above. But finite sets of reals have canonical choice functions in them: take the minimum. And this is a contradiction to the assumption that there is no choice function from $\{R_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$.

As a consequence we see that the "total extension principle" cannot be true if there exists an uncountable set $X$ generated by iterated countable unions from its singletons; and there is a choice function from finite subsets of $X^\omega$.

Comment: I will need a couple of days or so to go through the references you have provided. In the meanwhile, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sure. It's pretty late, so I might have had some serious oversight. Let me know if you notice anything fishy.

Comment: Asaf, perhaps I misunderstand, but you seem to imply in your remarks that every set in Gitik's model is a countable union of countable sets. But that is stronger than what I think is true there. Without that, you would seem to iterate the countable unions, but since the cardinals in Gitik's model are not well-founded (or are they?), I don't see how the iteration argument goes through. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Joel: Define a rank function, singletons have rank $0$, and now step up with countable unions of sets of lower rank. Then in Gitik's model you get the entire universe like that. The point being that generally, sigma algebras are already more or less power sets to begin with in this model.

Comment: But you seem to need that every set is a countable union of sets with smaller rank, and this is what I don't see.

Comment: @Joel: In the rank function I defined here? It's not obvious, and Gitik proves this in the ultimate or penultimate section of his paper.

Comment: Ah, ok. But this seems to be stronger than the claim merely that every set is the union of countably many smaller sets, and so I find your answer misleading ("To see why...").  Does Gitik prove that in fact that stronger claim follows just from the assumption that every set is a countable union of smaller sets? Or perhaps he just proves that it is true in his model, using the details of his forcing construction.

Comment: @Joel: You're probably right. But it will have to wait for the morning. :-) in any case, this is true in Gitik's model, and Arnie Miller gives some survey of this axiom (due to Specker if my memory serves me right)  in his paper also.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm having a hard time to read Gitik's paper, and I beg for your indulgence if anything in what I'm writing is wrong. So, it seems to me that Gitik starts with assuming the consistency of a set theory, ST, including the axioms of ZFC + the following: "For each $\alpha\in O$, there exist $\kappa>\alpha$ strongly compact cardinals", where $O$ is the class of all ordinals defined within ST. Then, he shows (Theorem 6.3) that in this set theory there is a set $V$ that models ZF and has the additional property that $V=G_{<\infty}:=\bigcup_{\alpha\in O}G_\alpha$, where $G_0$ is the (...)

Comment: (...) set of all countable subsets of $V$ and, for each $\alpha\in O$, we define (by transfinite induction) $G_{<\alpha}:=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}G_\beta$ and $$G_\alpha:=\left\{\bigcup_{n<\omega}X_n: (X_n)_{n<\omega}\text{ is a (countable) sequence of sets in }G_{<\alpha}\right\}.$$ Strictly speaking, the above is *not* the construction used by Gitik himself, but a variant of it, see the footnote on p. 2 of the paper by Miller cited in Asaf's answer (btw, both Gitik and Miller credit the construction to Specker, but Miller adds that Specker borrowed it from a 1927 TAMS paper by Church). (...)

Comment: (...) In turn, this allows for the natural introduction of a rank function $V\to O$ (cf. Definition 6.2 in Gitik's paper), which is the one Asaf is using, as far as I can say, in his answer, which I've not yet fully understood, though (in particular, I'm puzzled by the case where the measure is non-trivial). That's all I have to say for the moment (please correct me if necessary).

Comment: @Salvo: The idea is due to Specker, yes. Gitik "merely" proved that it's also consistent.

Comment: @Asaf. Yes, yes, I didn't mean anything different! As for your answer, let $\mu:\Sigma\to\bf R$ be a (non-negative, countably additive) measure on a set $X$ within Gitik's universe $V$. If $\mu(X)=0$ (viz., $\mu$ is trivial), then extending $\mu$ to the entire power set is obviously possible. Thus, assume from now on that $\mu(X)\ne 0$, and let $A_\mu$ be the set of atoms of $\mu$. You *seem* to argue as if $A_\mu$ should necessarily contain the $1$-element subsets of $X$, and that's what puzzles me the most. Would you mind to clarify this point for me? I'm definitely OK with the rest.

Comment: @Salvo: You're right, the argument is a bit off. I'll fix it later today! Thanks!

Comment: @Asaf. No problem, and actually thanks to you for having given me the chance to learn about Gitik's (amazing!) model.

Comment: @Salvo: I'm starting to think that if there is an atom which is not a singleton, then the measure cannot be extended (or rather if you can't choose from each atom a unique point). Because if singletons get $0$, then every set must have measure $0$.

Comment: @Asaf. I've the same feeling, but don't see how to turn it into a formal argument. What about editing your answer to make clear that the question in the OP is still unsolved? Hopefully, more people will be encouraged to think about it.

Comment: @Salvo: Let me think about it until the morning, and if I can't figure it out, I'll edit/delete my answer.

Comment: @Asaf. Sure, but please don't delete your answer! Even in the unfortunate case it shouldn't be fixable, I beg to say that it was quite instructive (at least for me).

Comment: @Salvo: I found a counterexample to the idea of using Gitik's model. I've added it to my answer, and at least for a while I will leave the answer here.

Comment: @Asaf. Sounds good, thanks. I will have to study your counterexample. I'll be back if I have any doubt or additional comment.